# wxpython: How do we remove null byte from string when using textcontrol.GetValue()

Tags: wxpython

Objective: Use two textcontrol boxes, one as an input and one as an output
However there is an additional step in the process, which fails likely because textcontrol.GetValue() returns null byte in addition

So say I have

```
self.tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)

self.tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
```

and I go about it

```
cmd = self.tc1.GetValue()
```

How do I exclude last character of string cmd (or any null byte)

Output:

TypeError: execv() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Comment: There is something wrong. `wx.TextCtrl.GetValue()` does not return `\0` characters as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out,

I had to change it to

```
cmd = self.tc1.GetValue().encode('ascii')
```

Comment: What is expected to happen in case someone inputs symbols not contained in ascii?

Comment: I edited question to show part of the log that hints it
Let me know if you want to see the rest

Comment: @phineas: It is expected to return `UnicodeEncodeError` exception :-).

Answer (score 1):

You simply use [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

```
>>> foo = "bar\n"
>>> foo
'bar\n'
>>> foo.strip()
'bar'
```

Note this also removes any leading and trailing whitespace.